# Update status on parent component in react/next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

component "footer":

```
  const Footer = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<'close' | 'open'>('close')
  const openImprint = () => {
    setStatus('open')
  }

 const closeImprint = () => {
   setStatus('close')
 }
 return (
   <>
  {status === 'open' && <Imprint onClose={setStatus}></Imprint>}
  {status === 'close' && (<div><a onClick={() => openImprint()}>xx</a></div>)
```

Component "imprint"

```
 const Imprint = (status) => {
 return (
   <div className={styles.close} onClick={() => setStatus('close')}>close</div>)
```

I would like to set the status on "footer" to close if I click on the close link at component imprint.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is right but the implementation is not.

On the Footer component you are assigning the "setStatus" setter to a property of the Imprint component called "onClose" but the Imprint component is neither exposing or using this property.

Try changing Imprint to this:

```
const Imprint = ({onClose}) => {
return (
  <div className={styles.close} onClick={() => onClose('close')}>close</div>
);}
```